# DAPR input bindings with multiple apps

Tags: kubernetes, event-handling, amazon-sqs, dapr

After reading into the Dapr docs, I'm left with a few questions regarding the behavior of input bindings. From what I understand, it's not possible to tell Dapr that a specific input binding should only trigger a specific endpoint of one particular app in a declarative sense. Rather, you create an input binding and define its endpoint (e.g. 'checkout'), and then dapr will test **all** apps for that endpoint. Correct?

If so then, tbh, I don't understand this design decision. For example, if the input binding is coming from a queue (e.g. SQS), then each item should only be processed once. But then, if multiple apps are automatically configured to process items from the queue simply because they have the same endpoint, how would you guarantee that the correct one does the job? Does this behavior change if the apps are in the same vs. differing namespaces?

In this use-case, this set-up is a big bummer since it means you cannot develop your apps independently (or else you risk running into naming collisions).

Hopefully I've missed a few details, so please correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Post is a bit old so maybe things have changed since the original question. I’ll attempt to close the loop though with the features available today.

My understanding is that a binding component, by default, is only scoped to the namespace. Therefore, only apps running within that namespace will be triggered by the input binding. This is not the k8s namespace and is more specifically the Dapr namespace.

Additionally, if you need to further refine things, components have a `scope` property where you can explicitly list the Dapr apps that can leverage the binding.

Further information can be found here: https://docs.dapr.io/operations/components/component-scopes/